# How to exit the activity in android in this case?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a quiz app with SQL and Firebase. First screens are SignUp/in activities, and after user is signed he is redirected to a splash screen which automatically navigates to PlayActivity. In play activity I wanted to handle the onBackPressedMethod, so that the user will close the game with the following code:

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

```
    if (backPressedTime + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Do you  want to exit?")
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> {

                    setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra("Exit", true));
                    System.exit(0);
                }).create().show();

    }else  {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Press Again to Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

The problem is, that after pressing the Yes button in the alert dialog, user is redirected to a previous SignUp activity, instead of exiting the game?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `finishAffinity()` in your SignUpActivity before you navigate to PlayActivity. This will remove the first `Activity` (and any below it) from the stack.